# Issue with layout alignment

Tags: android, textview, alignment

I have a relative layout with two linear layout inside it with two textviews in each of them.
I wanted the textviews to appear horizontally as a row.
The code is given below:

```
     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/txtlinear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/esms_parentfees_classtext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/esms_parentfees_classdetais"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/esms_parentfees_classdetais"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/esms_parentfees_datetext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/esms_parentfees_datedetais"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What exactly are you wanting? I'm confused... Perhaps a simple diagram?

Comment: Actually I have 4 textviews,each aligned horizontally.

Comment: why not u use just a linear layout instead of two linear layouts in a relative layouts...

Answer (score 1):

Notes on your XML:

- You can't use toRightOf, etc, within a LinearLayout
- RelativeLayout's don't have an orientation

This is needed for some reason to show all the XML? Ignore this line

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/esms_parentfees_classtext"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/esms_parentfees_classdetais"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/esms_parentfees_datetext"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/esms_parentfees_datedetais"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can use the `toRightOf` attribute if the parent view is a `RelativeLayout` which in his case, it is.

Comment: @DeeV - True but he was trying to align the LinearLayout to one of the TextViews within the LinearLayout.. Not sure how good of an idea that is

Comment: He is using toRightOf on a TextView within a LinearLayout, which itself in within a RelativeLayout - toRightOf can only be used on the LinearLayout, not the TextViews.

Edit - I misread his code - oops

Comment: Oh. I didn't notice that he was trying to align to the textview.  *That's* the problem. The TextView isn't within the scope of the second LinearLayout.  If he did `layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtlinear"`, it would fix his problem if for some reason he absolutely had to keep the RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to make the outer RelativeLayout a LinearLayout

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Then remove any tag like

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/esms_parentfees_classdetais"
```

Or, you could just change the tag mentioned above to

```
android:layout_below="@+id/esms_parentfees_classdetais"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need the four textviews in a row its easy to just use a linear layout with the four text views in it (or a table layout) instead of using two linear layouts in a relative layout.

Have a look at this :

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtlinear"
    >
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/esms_parentfees_classtext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="hi" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/esms_parentfees_classdetais"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="hi" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/esms_parentfees_datetext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="hi" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/esms_parentfees_datedetais"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="hi" />


</LinearLayout>
```

or

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtlinear"
 >

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/esms_parentfees_classtext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="hi" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/esms_parentfees_classdetais"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="hi" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/esms_parentfees_datetext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="hi" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/esms_parentfees_datedetais"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="hi" />
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

or if its a compulsion that you need a relative layout with two linear layouts in it you can follow any of the solutions above

Answer (score -1):

```
<RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/esms_parentfees_classtext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
            <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/esms_parentfees_classdetais"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/esms_parentfees_classtext"
                 />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this won't distribute the button width evenly.. and you only have the first row in there

Comment: yea you are right I heavent even read the post completely...sorry